# How to deserialze this json array in c# blazor?

Tags: c#, json, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to deserialize this json array in a server side c# Blazor project:

```
[
    {
        "buy": {
            "forQuery": {
                "bid": true,
                "types": [
                    16265
                ],
                "regions": [
                    10000002
                ],
                "systems": [
                    30000142
                ],
                "hours": 24,
                "minq": 1
            },
            "volume": 12177,
            "wavg": 118125.12,
            "avg": 118260.00,
            "variance": 58000.00,
            "stdDev": 240.83,
            "median": 118100.00,
            "fivePercent": 118466.60,
            "max": 118600.00,
            "min": 118000.00,
            "highToLow": true,
            "generated": 1655337615423
        },
        "sell": {
            "forQuery": {
                "bid": false,
                "types": [
                    16265
                ],
                "regions": [
                    10000002
                ],
                "systems": [
                    30000142
                ],
                "hours": 24,
                "minq": 1
            },
            "volume": 935,
            "wavg": 178386.31,
            "avg": 194183.33,
            "variance": 3731725666.67,
            "stdDev": 61087.85,
            "median": 140350.00,
            "fivePercent": 134900.00,
            "max": 250000.00,
            "min": 134900.00,
            "highToLow": false,
            "generated": 1655337615423
        }
    }
]
```

For reference, if you'd like to see the json data on the source api, it's this: https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=16265&usesystem=30000142

From all this information I only need:
buy -> min, max
sell -> min, max

I have created a class that contains these 2 properties:

```
public class BuySellStat
{
    public double max;
    public double min;
}
```

and would like to save them into this class:

```
public class EveMarketerResponse
{
    public BuySellStat Buy;
    public BuySellStat Sell;        
}
```

I have tried many things, like deserializing into a Dictionary, List, Array... but cannot get it done. It always fails on the deserialization.

Would somebody please help me out here?

Thank you so much!

EDIT1:

I have tried it according to the sample Yong Shun shared, but get a Nullreference Exception in the first line of tthe foreach loop:

```
var list = HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<EveMarketerResponse>>("https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=16265&usesystem=30000142").Result;
        
        await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync(list.Count.ToString()); //Will show in the browser console.
        foreach (var response in list)
        {
            await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync(response.Buy.min.ToString());
            await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync(response.Buy.max.ToString());
            await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync(response.Sell.min.ToString());
            await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync(response.Sell.min.ToString());
        }
```

EDIT 2:

This one seems to work:

```
 var responseJson = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=16265&usesystem=30000142");
        var responseList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EveMarketerResponse>>(responseJson);
        
         
       
        
        foreach (var response in responseList)
        {
            await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("buy min" + response.Buy.min.ToString());
            await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("buy max" + response.Buy.max.ToString());
            await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("sell min" + response.Sell.min.ToString());
            await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("sell max" + response.Sell.max.ToString());
        }
```

this one does not

```
  var list = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<EveMarketerResponse>>("https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=16265&usesystem=30000142");
    
    foreach (var response in list)
    {
        await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("buy min" + response.Buy.min.ToString());
        await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("buy max" + response.Buy.max.ToString());
        await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("sell min" + response.Sell.min.ToString());
        await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("sell max" + response.Sell.max.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Deserialize as `List<EveMarketerResponse>` looks fine. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WvsDww). Can you provide the code on how you deserialize it and specify what do you mean *fails on the deserialization*, get any exception or? Also may consider applying the JsonProperty attribute to match the JSON property name

Comment: thank you for getting back to me. please see the Edit1 section

Comment: I have shared away that works. is `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` safe to use compared to `HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync`? `HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync` does not work for some reason :/

Comment: you could also try ReadAsStreamAsync is a bit more efficient than GetStringAsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your support!

This one seems to work:

var responseJson = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=16265&usesystem=30000142");
var responseList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(responseJson);

```
    foreach (var response in responseList)
    {
        await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("buy min" + response.Buy.min.ToString());
        await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("buy max" + response.Buy.max.ToString());
        await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("sell min" + response.Sell.min.ToString());
        await JsConsoleLogger.LogAsync("sell max" + response.Sell.max.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using NewtonSoft

```cs
public class BuySellStat
{
    [JsonProperty("max")]
    public double max;
    [JsonProperty("min")]
    public double min;
}
```

to deserialize :

```cs
public BuySellStat Deserialize<BuySellStat>(string result)
        {
            BuySellStat model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuySellStat>(result);

            if (model == null)
            {
                return default;
            }

            return model;
        }
```